Aalen Additive Model Validation
I am using Aalen's additive hazards model in R because I found via the Schoenfeld test that my covariates do not meet the proportional hazards assumption. I want to use this model and I am trying to understand if my assumptions hold. However, when I try to access the residuals of my model, it says they are NULL. Do you know how I can check if this model is appropriate to use? On the other hand I am trying to validate this model via train-test resampling and looking for cindex, but when I try to predict on my test set predict can allocate this info it seems that is computationally expensive. How can I validate this model in other way?
aalen_model <- aalen(Surv(EmployeeLifeTime, Censored) ~ Cluster + Modality + Industry, data = df)

All three of my covariates are factors with no colinearity problems. I have 14350 deads and 12000 Censore Data
names(aalen_model)
"cum"               "var.cum"           "robvar.cum"        "residuals" "pval.testBeq0"     "obs.testBeq0"      "pval.testBeqC"     "pval.testBeqC.is" "obs.testBeqC"      "obs.testBeqC.is"   "sim.testBeq0"      "sim.testBeqC" "sim.testBeqC.is"   "conf.band"         "test.procBeqC"     "sim.test.procBeqC" "covariance"        "B.iid"             "stratum"           "call"

aalen_model$residuals
None

I have checked plot(aalen_model) and it seems reasonable to me. When I run summary(aalen_model), all p-values are < 0.05, which suggests that all my covariates are significant for this model. Additionally, none of my covariates satisfy the proportional hazards assumption.
For validation I try
cv_function <- function(data, indices) {
    fit <- aalen(Surv(Tenure, Censored) ~ Cluster + Modality + Industry_grouped,data = data[indices, ], resample.iid = 1)

columns_to_use <- c("Cluster", "Modality", "Industry_grouped")
validation_data <- data[-indices, columns_to_use]
pred <- predict(fit, newdata = validation_data)
c_index <- concordance.index(pred, data[-indices, "Tenure"], data[-indices, "Censored"])
return(c_index$c.index)}

cv_results <- boot(data = df, statistic = cv_function, R = 3)

this results on an error in predict
